# How do I retrieve the value of a column of a MySQL table into code?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public String User;
Model.JDBC j=new JDBC();
/**
 * Creates new form Home_Page
 */
public Home_Page(String eid) 
{
    initComponents();

    User=eid;
    Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d = t.getScreenSize();
    int w = (int) d.getWidth();
    int h = (int) d.getHeight()-40;
    setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    jLabel2.setText(new Controler.getDate().date());
    time();
    jLabel3.setText(eid);
    ResultSet rs;

    try 
    {

      rs = j.getData("select eid from user where eid='"+eid+"'");          
      System.out.println(rs.next()+ " rs.next");

      if(rs.next() != true)
      {

            System.out.println("rs.next");
           //until this point it works but gives an exception
           if(rs.getString(3).equals("Admin"))
           {

                System.out.println("if admin");

                home.setEnabled(true);
                job.setEnabled(true);
                employee.setEnabled(true);
                user.setEnabled(true);
                machine.setEnabled(true);
                branch.setEnabled(true);

            }
            else if(rs.getString(3).equals("user"))
            {
                System.out.println("else if");

                home.setEnabled(true);
                job.setEnabled(false);
                employee.setEnabled(false);
                user.setEnabled(false);
                machine.setEnabled(true);
                branch.setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("user can't see");
            }
            else
            {
                 System.out.println("else");
            }
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("outer else executed");
                  }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Home_Page.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Through this I am trying to filter the ability of clicking jbuttons that appear in my  Home_Page for normal users while permitting the Admin to see them and click them.
But after the first if it doesn't work properly.

Exception says like this..

```
 true rs.next
    rs.next
    Model.JDBC@15bc725
    working
    Mar 15, 2017 3:20:39 PM Viewer.Home_Page <init>
    SEVERE: null
    java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
    at Viewer.Home_Page.<init>(Home_Page.java:65)
    at Viewer.login.loginActionPerformed(login.java:119)
    at Viewer.login.access$000(login.java:18)
    at Viewer.login$1.actionPerformed(login.java:70)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

MySQL table name is user and the column name of third  column is ulevel and the two values entered so far under varchar type are "user" and "Admin". Could you please give me a hand in here to sort this out and make the ifs work to get those jbuttons unclickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to iterate over the ResultSet by rs.next() method and then get the column values by any of the ResultSet getters.
for example,

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement ();
s.executeQuery ("SELECT id, name FROM user");
ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
rs = statement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
    int name = resultSet.getInt("name");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sumit.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You call two time `rs.next()`.
That leads to an error, if you only have one record in the resultset.The second problem is that you access the third column `rs.getString(3)` and you only select one.

Comment: It worked. Thanks in heaps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query return `eid` so only one value, but you rs.getString(3):

```
rs = j.getData("select eid from user where eid='"+eid+"'");    
//----------------------^^---------------------------------      
if(rs.getString(3).equals("Admin"))
//--------------^-----------------
```

Instead you have to use :

```
if(rs.getString(1).equals("Admin"))
//--------------^-----------------
```

Isuggest to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead this can cause syntax error or [SQL Injection](https://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection)

Instead of :

```
rs = j.getData("select eid from user where eid='"+eid+"'");
```

you have to use

```
rs = j.executeQuery("select eid from user where eid = ?");
rs.setString(1, eid);
```

**NOTE**

Like @Jens said in his answer, you will get an error if you are using two `rs.next()` but not avoid it wiht `hasnext` this is not exist in ResultSet so to avoid this you have to re-execute `result` after your check like this :

```
System.out.println("----------->" + (result.next()));
result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much YCF_L... I'll try this and tell weather it worked for me.. :)

Comment: It worked YCF_L .... Thanks again and again.. I must appreciate the simple way you explained it and the clarity of it.. :)

Comment: no problem @Jay enjoy